# Write specific lines of a .txt file ( containing large no of lines) to a new txt files

Tags: python, tensor

I have a text (.txt) file in tensor format as follows:

```
[tensor([[5.7744e+02, 1.7730e+02, 6.2396e+02, 2.1678e+02, 9.9988e-01],
    [5.8410e+02, 1.7532e+02, 6.2769e+02, 2.1083e+02, 9.9969e-01],
    [6.4279e+02, 1.7254e+02, 6.7784e+02, 2.0478e+02, 9.9957e-01],
    [6.9179e+02, 1.6719e+02, 8.2207e+02, 2.6694e+02, 9.9954e-01],
   [1.0050e+03, 2.9167e+02, 1.0792e+03, 3.7500e+02, 5.7740e-05]],
   device='cuda:0')]
[tensor([[7.6615e+02, 1.7577e+02, 8.2579e+02, 2.0013e+02, 9.9981e-01],
    [7.7214e+02, 1.7320e+02, 8.3133e+02, 1.9800e+02, 9.9901e-01],
    [6.3909e+02, 1.7303e+02, 6.6037e+02, 1.8797e+02, 9.9790e-01],
    [7.6184e+02, 1.7468e+02, 8.3014e+02, 2.0274e+02, 9.9395e-01],
   [6.9179e+02, 1.6719e+02, 8.2207e+02, 2.6694e+02, 9.9954e-01],
   [1.0050e+03, 2.9167e+02, 1.0792e+03, 3.7500e+02, 5.7740e-05]],
   device='cuda:0')]
```

How do I write each tensor to a new (.txt) file. For example I want:

```
[tensor([[5.7744e+02, 1.7730e+02, 6.2396e+02, 2.1678e+02, 9.9988e-01],
    [5.8410e+02, 1.7532e+02, 6.2769e+02, 2.1083e+02, 9.9969e-01],
    [6.4279e+02, 1.7254e+02, 6.7784e+02, 2.0478e+02, 9.9957e-01],
    [6.9179e+02, 1.6719e+02, 8.2207e+02, 2.6694e+02, 9.9954e-01],
   [1.0050e+03, 2.9167e+02, 1.0792e+03, 3.7500e+02, 5.7740e-05]],
   device='cuda:0')]
```

this tensor in file one.txt
and another tensor to two.txt and so on.

Comment: can you open the file, and just loop through it, watching for `"[tensor"` ?

Comment: first correct question and format correctly your data

Comment: it seems you have empty line between tensors - so maybe you should read it as text file and split it using  this empty line - it means two new lines `text.split("\n\n")` - and then you should have list with tensors in separated strings.

Comment: I just corrected the format, there is not empty line in between tensors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Matrkeenerh's suggestion, if we put your file as `input.txt` then you can do something pretty simple.

```
file_in = 'input.txt'

counter = 0 # counter used ofr the output files

with open(file_in, 'r') as fin:    
    line = fin.readline() # read file in line by line
    while line: # so long as line is not empty,
                # if you do have blank lines in your file
                # you'd need to do something else
        if 'tensor' in line:
            # the very first time there won't be a fout so use try
            # there are other options, like "if count > 0", etc.
            try:
                fout.close() # close the old file
            except:
                pass
            # augment the counter and open a new file
            counter += 1 
            fout = open('output_%03d.txt' % counter, 'w')
        fout.write(line) # write the line to the output file
        line = fin.readline() # read the next line of the input file
fout.close() # close the last output file
```

This will create files like `output_001.txt`, `output_002.txt`, etc. with the output you're looking for.

Note that I've chosen above to read through the file line by line. If the file isn't big, you can just read it all in at once with something like

```
with open(file_in, 'r'):
      lines = fid.readlines()
for line in lines:
      if 'tensor' in line:
            ...
            ...
      fout.write(line)
fout.close()
```

There are potentially easier ways to do this. For example if your file is consistent and each `tensor` entry is on 6 lines of your input file, then you can just start a new file every six lines, with something like. Or you can just keep everything in the one giant file, knowing where in the file to look, since entry `n` would start on line `(n-1) * 6 + 1`.